# Seed database with strings containing new lines using EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to seed my database from code using migrations:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().HasData(
                new MyClass
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Some name",
                    Description = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, "String1", "String2", "String3"),
                    IconPath = "pathtoImg"
                },
                ... more objects
);
```

After the migration is created and applied, the output looks like this:

```
String1\r\n                    String2\r\n                        String3
```

It creates additional spaces between the new lines. I found out that it's an issue with EF Core here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20662

But I have already written hundreds of lines to do this and was wondering if there is a workaround to fix this issue without having to re-write all the strings?

Comment: You could always write a follow up migration that SQL LTRIMs all the data! (But why does updating efcore to one that doesn't have the bug, then dumping the db or rolling it back to pre-the-migrate-with-the-problem and doing the migrate again with the fixed ef not work?)